# Community download page at Magento.com

Tags: magento-community, download

Is it just me or is the page for downloading the new & older versions of magento broken?

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

If this is the case, I know its been like this for a while and have finally got round to asking on here as the magento facebook user said to post in the forums..

...and where do we go to download the latest versions..

**EDIT**

Firefox browser v45
browser cache cleared

below is the full page, its like the content area is just gone

[image: Magento Community Download page]

This is the inspect element code, as you can see the main content div is empty

```
 <div class="main col3-layout">
            <div class="col-wrapper">
                <div class="col-main">
                                        </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right sidebar"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: page is working properly. problem at you end. try with other browser or clear the cache .

Comment: see question edits

Comment: chrome seems to work okay..

Comment: use any proxy website to be sure that is this not your ISP problem

Comment: using hide.me with a US proxy fixes the issue in firefox..but why would it be an ISP issue if it works in chrome

Comment: Same problem for me on Firefox it started happening start of the year

Comment: Then someone need to report it on magento.. So that they can take a look on this issue

Comment: Working on Firefox 46.

Answer (score 1):

I have just check link and it has been working.

At **Release Archive** tab,You can download Old 1.X version also.

May be you at your system,you  may have any downloader software.It may be cause the problem.

Comment: see question edits